# Angular 4 migration errors

Tags: angular

I have been trying to upgrade our project from Angular 2.0.0 to 4.0.0 through incremental changes because migrating to Angular 4 directly did not help me. There were no issues till 4.0.0-beta.6. 
When I upgraded to Angular 4.0.0-beta.6, I see the following error

```
ERROR in [default] node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.d.ts:15:47
Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
```

As suggested in the ChangeLog by Angular, I added `es2015.iterable.ts"` to `lib` in `tsconfig.json`. No other dependencies were upgraded.

```
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "^0.7.4",
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
"typings": "^0.8.1",
```

Comment: You missed [TypeScript version](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#typescript-21). 4.0 works with TS 2.1+

Comment: @Sasxa When I upgrade typescript to ^2.1.4, I get the following errors in addition to the `Iterable` error,

`ERROR in [default]
File '/node_modules/bootstrap-loader/loader.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.`

`ERROR in [default] /typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts:426:10
Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'.
  Types of property 'fill' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: any, offset?: number, end?: number) => Buffer' is not assignable to type '(value: number, start?: number, end?: number) => this'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing `Typings` to 1.x version and adding `/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />` at the beginning of `main.ts` helped me eliminate this issue.

Also Typescript@2.1.5 gave a lot errors. Downgrading to Typescript@2.0.3 helped.

Comment: Adding "typings": "2.1.1" to my package.json helped. Thx